# Turn off CUDA in OpenCV installation?

Tags: macos, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV on Mac OSX. I had previously installed CUDA 5.0 but no longer have an NVIDIA GPU and thought I had uninstalled the CUDA drivers. However when I run cmake on the OpenCV source it says it detects CUDA and configures the installation to use it, which then causes the installation to crash due to said lack of GPU or nvcc. How do I turn off this option in the configuration? How can I completely scrub any last trace of CUDA from my system, so that it's not erroneously detected?

Answer (score 7):

Basicly you have only to be sure that the flag `WITH_CUDA` is deselected. While autoconfiguration during cmake process, OpenCV search for CUDA on the system, for example through references in the environment variables.
To disable CUDA support, add following commandline option:

```
cmake -DWITH_CUDA:BOOL="0"
```

Alternatively if you uses a gui for cmake, just search for the `WITH_CUDA` option and deselect it or set it to `OFF`